# Why does .Dump(#) cause my results to double?

Tags: linqpad

When I run an OData query with LinqPad, I sometimes need more than the standard 3 levels of nesting/expanding.

I found online that you can call `Dump(int nestingLevel)` to get more levels of nesting.

But when I do that I get two result sets.  (One with my expanded nesting, and one as it would be without the `.Dump` call.)

Why is that?  Is there a way I can turn that off?

As an example connect to https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/atom and run this query:

```
Posts.Take(1).Select(x=>new{x.Title}).Dump(1)
```

You will get two identical result sets.  Like this:

[image: LinqPad Double]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you run a `C# Expression` query, the query's result is automatically dumped.

LINQPad compiles the code

```
LINQPad.Dump(
    //Your code here
);
```

Your code calls `Dump()` too, so you're dumping the object before returning to the outer generated `Dump()` call.
(`Dump()` returns its argument to allow chaining)

You only need to `Dump()` in a `C# Statements` (or higher) query, or if you want to dump something else.